# endless loop on code analysis with FxCop Introspection

Tags: stack-overflow, code-analysis, fxcop, cyclic-reference

I'm trying to write a custom FxCop code analysis rule
that will warn developers from methods containing too deeply nested code blocks,
and will urge them to re-factor out the mess.

ex. I'm trying to avoid the following situation:

```
if(condition)
{
   foreach(var item in items)
   {
       if(anotherCondition)
       {
           for(var product in item.Products)
           {
               // even more nested statement blocks...
           }
       }
   }
}
```

I get a stackoverflow when I override the `VisitBlock(Block block)` method
that counts the block's depth, because apparently, there is a cyclic reference
from one of the properties of the block to 
the block itself.
i.e. the following is true for some i:  block.Statements[i] == block

Why does such a cyclic reference exist? How to avoid it?
Thanks!

Comment: Please provide sample code (for both the rule and the target) that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after some more research, I've figured out I had actually TWO main problems

1. The VisitXXX methods are not visiting nodes in an abstract syntax tree of the ***source code***
   but actually visit nodes in the generated IL. Just compare the generated IL instructions per method
   and the generated statements per method.Body.
   I wonder what we could have achieved if FxCop 
   could provide us with a true AST visitor?
2. To answer my initial question, to prevent developers of writing too many nested
   code blocks, we should just scan the method code by ourselves, I mean, take out the start line and the end line inside the `SourceContext` property of the `method.Body` and keep track of every 
   '{' and '}' we find. Increment counter for '{' and decrement counter for '}'. That should work, right?